# Update SDK: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I'm using `Android Studio 2.3.3` and updated my SDK version and now I'm using API 27 but I encountered the following error:

[image]

Also I install repository and sync project but This error occurred:

[image]

**This code is gradle.build (project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Also this code is gradle.build (Module:app )**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "comp.packk.ir"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' 
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Change gradle from  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'    to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'  in your gradle.build (project) try this

Comment: Add `google()` in your gradle (Project) in `repositories`

Comment: I change classpath but comming this Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.jar

Comment: With adding google() to gradle(project), this error comming: Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Comment: You need to update android studio to 3.1

Comment: I things is because you have not installed the google package in android studio

Comment: How can i install google pack. off course i have 3 folders in sdk: (extras/google/)

Comment: File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK tools -> Support Repository -> Google Repository.

Comment: I checked, Google Repository version 58 installed.

Comment: I update android studio to version 3.1.3 but this error comming:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: I disable offline mode, but this error occurred:Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implementation or compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation or compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation or compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I did it but I encountered this  Error:Connection timed out: connect

Comment: try to build gradle again

Comment: I build gradle again but this error comming: Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.jar

Comment: You have to update your gradle version i think it could help

i think it look like 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' To
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'